# Struggling With Btree Algorithm

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, b-tree

I've tried using Java to implement algorithms from the textbook Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd edition, without a lot of success. Almost every time I try to implement them I encounter a multitude of errors, to the point where I'm not sure if the authors themselves have tried implementing their own pseudocode. But specifically, in this case, I'm having problems with the Btree algorithm. I think the problem lies somewhere in the B-Tree-Insert-Nonfull method. When I try to run the program, this line causes a Null Pointer Exception:

int i = x.totalKeys - 1;

However, that doesn't make any sense. All Nodes, like x in this case, are initialized with a value of 0 in their constructors, so how is his error even occurring?  I'm going to enclose the function below:

```
public void bTreeInsertNonfull(Node x, Integer k)
{
    int i = x.totalKeys - 1;
    if (x.leaf || (x.children[i] == null))
    {
        while( (i >= 0) && (k < x.keys[i]) )
        {
            x.keys[i+1] = x.keys[i];
            i = i - 1;
        }
        x.keys[i+1] = k;
        x.totalKeys = x.totalKeys + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while ( (i >= 0) && x.keys[i] != null)
        {
            if (k < x.keys[i])
            {
                i = i - 1;
            }
        }

        i = i + 1;

        if ((x.children[i] != null) && (x.children[i].totalKeys == tUpper))
        {
            bTreeSplitChild( x, i, x.children[i] );
            if (k > x.keys[i])
            {
                i = i + 1;
            }
        }
        bTreeInsertNonfull(x.children[i], k);
    }
}
```

Comment: is `x` null or is `x.totalkeys` null? posting the code to a function where the null reference happens on the first line does not help us (edit: it's a recursive function so maybe the error actually is in this function) - the error is caused because either the Node `x` passed to the function is null or the variable `x.totalkeys` is not initialized.

Comment: Check if arrays in book are indexed from 1, as they often are in algorithm pseudocode, and make sure you adapt your Java code (which indexes arrays from 0). Either make 1 bigger Java arrays and leave index 0 unused, or adapt algorithm to use indexes one smaller than in pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on the idea from Alex: if you look at the last part of the algorithm, there is a line that says:

```
if ((x.children[i] != null) && (x.children[i].totalKeys == tUpper))
```

That hints that `x.children[i] == null` is a possibility. The last line of the algorithm calls `bTreeInsertNonfull(x.children[i], k);` without checking if the first parameter is null.

Comment: Okay, guys, that gave me some nice tips to fix this mess. Thanks.